# Getting rank for baby name popularity ranking program

Tags: c#, console, readline, ranking

I'm trying to get this program finished but keep running into issues, I can't figure out how to get the count for ranking for the result I keep getting 1 for my output and I'm trying to get this finished as soon as I can. The output should look something like this :

Enter the directory path of the data files: C:\Intel 
Enter the year:2010 
Enter the gender (M/F): M 
Enter the name: Javier

Javier is ranked #190 in year 2010

```
namespace QuestionTwo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> names = new List<string>();

            Console.Write("Enter the directory path of the data files: ");
            string filename = Console.ReadLine();
            filename.Replace(@"\", @"\\");

            Console.Write("Enter the year: ");
            string year = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter the gender (M/F): ");
            string gender = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.Write("Enter the name: ");
             string name = Console.ReadLine();

            filename += "\\yob" + year + ".txt";
            string line = "";
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader fin = new StreamReader(filename))
                {
                    while((line = fin.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        string[] parsed = line.Split(',');

                        if (parsed[1] == gender)
                        {
                                names.Add(parsed[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (names[i] == (name)) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(name + " is ranked #" + i + " in year " + year);
                    }
                    else //if (names[i] != (name)) // it is a logic error somewhere here 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The name " + name
                            + " is not ranked in year " + year);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e  )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The file at {0} could not be read."+ e,  filename);
            }

            for(int c = 0; c < names.Count; c++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine((c + 1) + ". " + names[c]);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try debugging the code to make sure the values are what you expect.

Comment: i did and it stayed at one

Comment: Did you got the real value from file?

Comment: In this part `for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)` is names has an exact content that you needed?

Comment: Try to add a real sample data like from your .text file.

Comment: ill edit the code and show u guys what the content of the file shows, it shows the number of times people used the name and the name next to it , name is the name user enters and names is the list name array for the files contents.Mary,F,7065
Anna,F,2604
Emma,F,2003
Elizabeth,F,1939
Minnie,F,1746
Margaret,F,1578
Ida,F,1472
Alice,F,1414
Bertha,F,1320
Sarah,F,1288
Annie,F,1258
Clara,F,1226
Ella,F,1156
Florence,F,1063
Cora,F,1045
Martha,F,1040Glenn,M,43
Jefferson,M,43
Luke,M,43
Neal,M,43
Burt,M,42
Ike,M,42
Myron,M,42
Tony,M,42
Conrad,M,41
Joel,M,41
Matt,M,41
Riley,M,41

Answer (score 0):

Your program outputs too much because you are printing *"The name " + name
                            + " is not ranked in year " + year"* for each name that doesn't match.

You need to add a flag to record whether you found the name while looking through the list, something like this: note I have also added a `break` keyword - once you've found the name, there's no need to continue looking.

You also need to subtract 1 from `i` to the output as your list starts from 0 and I expect you don't want a zero-based rank?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>();

        string filename = @"c:\temp\baby.txt";
        string year = "1997";
        string gender = "F";
        string name = "Margaret";

        string line = "";
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader fin = new StreamReader(filename))
            {
                while((line = fin.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] parsed = line.Split(',');

                    if (parsed[1] == gender)
                    {
                            names.Add(parsed[0]);
                    }
                }
            }

            bool foundName = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
            {
                if (names[i] == (name)) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(name + " is ranked #" + i-1 + " in year " + year);
                    foundName = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!foundName)
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("The name " + name
                        + " is not ranked in year " + year);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e  )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file at {0} could not be read."+ e,  filename);
        }

        for(int c = 0; c < names.Count; c++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((c + 1) + ". " + names[c]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output:

> Margaret is ranked #4 in year 1997
>   The name Doris is not ranked in year 1997

Notes:

- Your search is case-sensitive so *"margaret"* doesn't match
- Your gender check is also case-sensitive so *"f"* doesn't find a match

Comment: The number after the gender is to tell how many people used that name but I'm looking for the index number I believe to get the rank because when the user enters m or f it automatically separates them into separate arrays

Comment: I've changed my answer.